# Refactored escaping closure not giving expected values

Tags: ios, swift

I started learning MVVM and API data fetching, so I made this code:

Function *newDirector* in which directorName value is modified with fetched data:

```
func newDirector(id: Int, completed: @escaping () -> ()){
    homeRepository.getDirector(id: id){ (creditReponse) -> (Void) in
        self.directorName = ""
        creditReponse?.crew.forEach({ singleValue in
            if singleValue.knownForDepartment == .directing {
                self.directorName = singleValue.name
                
            }
        })
        completed()
    }
}
```

Function *getDirector* which is used for data fetch from Internet:

```
func getDirector(id:Int, _ completed: @escaping (CreditsResponse?) -> (Void)) {
    movieServiceAPI.fetchData(from: NetworkData.directorUrl(id: id).value, by: completed)
}
```

Function *loadDirector* in which *newDirector* is called and it is ViewModel function.

```
func loadDirector(id: Int){
    newDirector(id: id, completed: {
        
    })
    
}
```

Function *loadDirector* is called in tableview function in VC:

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
    
    let movie = homeViewModel.movieList[indexPath.row]
    homeViewModel.loadDirector(id: movie.id)

    self.changeVC(movie: movie, director: (self.homeViewModel.directorName), groups: self.homeViewModel.setupGenres(groups: movie.genreIds), movieIndex: indexPath.row)
}
```

Firstly it was *homeViewModel.loadDirector(id: movie.id, completed: )* and changeVC was called in *completed* closure, but I wanted to refactor code in which *loadDirector* only have one parameter. When I execute this code on first cell click *directorName* value is "" and on second cell click *directorName* has value from previous click. I know it is because *changeVC* is called before data fetch is completed, but I dont know to change *loadDirector* complete closure so it works well.

Answer (score 0):

As your `loadDirector` method is async, you need to add `completion` block parameter to this method as well and call `self.changeVC` inside this completion block